# Hibernate one to many mapping for multiple tables

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, maven, hibernate-mapping

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Visit")
public class Visit {
    @Id
    @XmlTransient
    @JsonIgnore
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "v_id_seq", sequenceName = "v_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "v_id_seq")
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "Visit",cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST,orphanRemoval = true,fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<directions> directions;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "Visit",cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST,orphanRemoval = true,fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Test> Test;
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name="test")
public class Test {
    @Id
    @XmlTransient
    @JsonIgnore
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "t_id_seq", sequenceName = "t_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "t_id_seq")
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JsonBackReference
    @JoinColumn(name = "vid", updatable = false, insertable = true,referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Visit visit;
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name="direction")
public class directions {
    @Id
    @XmlTransient
    @JsonIgnore
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "d_id_seq", sequenceName = "d_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "d_id_seq")
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JsonBackReference
    @JoinColumn(name = "vid", updatable = false, insertable = true,referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Visit Visit;
```

Hello i am new to hibernate
I am trying to map OneToMany Visit-->Test and Visit-->direction but getting error
`Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property:`

one visit can have multiple direction and test
how can i implement this?

plz help me!

Comment: Can you share the full console log? And why is that directions entity in lowercase? I mean it should be Directions not directions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of the `mappedBy` field on the `@OneToMany` annotation references java instance variable names, and it is case sensitive. You are setting it to `Visit`, but in the `directions` and `test` classes the variable names are `visit`.

The solution is to change property `mappedBy` from `Visit` to `visit` (lower case V):

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "visit",cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST,orphanRemoval = true,fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
private List<directions> directions;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "visit",cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST,orphanRemoval = true,fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
private List<Test> Test;
```